# How do I read a matrix from a file?

Tags: c, file, matrix

I know this same question has been asked a hundred times before, but they either don't help me or they aren't answered.

I want to read a text file which has some integers in a format like this:

```
1;50
2;40
3;180
```

this file can go forever so I can't create an array with a fixed size. So far the summarized part of what I have done (full code isn't like this, I have checked if files aren't null, made file pointers, put them in different functions etc.) :

```
int **mymatrix;
mymatrix =(int **) malloc(sizeof(int*)*1);
fscanf(file, "%d", &mymatrix[0]);
fscanf(file, ";%d", &mymatrix[1]);
```

and to print that:

```
printf("%d",  *mymatrix[0]);
printf(" %d", *mymatrix[0]);
```

I have looked some similar questions and learned the malloc line from them. 
I have tried doing `fscanf(file, "%d;%d", something)` and replaced something with every possible combination of *, **, &, && and also tried [0], [1] but still can't read anything.

I don't need that print part on my code (also tried every possible combinations but no luck). I had placed breakpoints after scanf's but Visual Studio shows mymatrix as < unable to read memory >.

So, there should be a combination of scanf that I haven't tried. If anyone can help me on that part, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 1) There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code and nothing which can be used as one. 2) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Are both numbers in your file `int`, `unsigned`, or limited to the range of `short`, or can they be `long` or `int64_t`?? That would help with the design of a correct solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin they are both integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    int d1, d2, rows = 0;
    while(2 == fscanf(fp, "%d;%d", &d1, &d2))
        ++rows;
    int **matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(*matrix));

    rewind(fp);
    rows = 0;
    while(2 == fscanf(fp, "%d;%d", &d1, &d2)){
        matrix[rows] = malloc(2 * sizeof(**matrix));
        matrix[rows][0] = d1;
        matrix[rows++][1] = d2;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //print and free'd
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        printf("%d %d\n", matrix[r][0], matrix[r][1]);
        free(matrix[r]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

---

realloc version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int **matrix = NULL;
    int d1, d2, r, rows = 0;

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    while(2 == fscanf(fp, "%d;%d", &d1, &d2)){
        matrix = realloc(matrix, (rows+1)*sizeof(*matrix));//In the case of large files increase the size that you want to extend. It must have control of the timing.
        matrix[rows] = malloc(2 * sizeof(**matrix));
        matrix[rows][0] = d1;
        matrix[rows][1] = d2;
        ++rows;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //print and free'd
    for(r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        printf("%d %d\n", matrix[r][0], matrix[r][1]);
        free(matrix[r]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the case of large files, it is faster to `realloc` than reading the file twice.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio to compile, so I think I should use @Priyansh Goel's malloc definition. VS keeps giving CL.exe not found error, so I am going to repair it, and it takes more than an hour. I am accepting this answer, but thanks to anybody who helped.

Comment: And also, does fscanf returns 2 because it read 2 different variables?

Comment: @acon__ It means that it has successfully read of two elements.

Comment: Does using `free(matrix[r]);` required if there is a `free(matrix);` at the end?

Comment: It is required in reverse order reserved.

Comment: One last question, at the while loop, am I allowed to use `matrix[rows] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` instead of `matrix[rows] = malloc(2 * sizeof(**matrix));` ?

Comment: they will be the same if `int **matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

First, `int **mymatrix;` is not a matrix/2D array and cannot represent one.

Said that, you should use a pointer to a 1D array/matrix:

```
// avoid magic numbers!
#define COLS 2

// Points to the matrix. Starts without matrix
int (*mymatrix)[COLS] = NULL;
```

Despite its type, it can point to a 2D array. As a general rule, a "pointer to an array of `N` dimensions" can be used to address an "array of `N+1` dimensions.

```
// the amount to grow the array (min. 1, but that is inefficient)
#define GROW_LENGTH 10

// this holds the total number of rows in the array
size_t length = 0;

// row to store next entry
size_t row = 0;

// buffer for input data
int buffer[COLS];

// read data until failure
while ( scanf("%d;%d", &buffer[0], &buffer[1]) == 2 ) {

    if ( row >= length ) {

        // enlarge the array for another block
        int (*p)[COLS] = realloc(mymatrix,
                sizeof(*mymatrix) * (length + GROW_LENGTH));

        if ( p == NULL ) {
            // realloc failed

            // release the matrix and terminate (can be changed to more inteligent behaviour)
            free(mymatrix);
            exit(1);
        }

        // update variables
        mymatrix = p;
        length += GROW_LENGTH;
    }

    // store the data into the matrix
    mymatrix[row][0] = buffer[0];
    mymatrix[row][1] = buffer[1];

    // next position in buffer
    row++;
}

if ( mymatrix == NULL ) {
    // nothing has been read
}

// process the data. 
// `row` contains the number of rows with data
```

Don't forget to release the array when done:

```
free(mymatrix);
```

The code above is a fragment. It requires some standard headers and a function, of course. Best is to wrap the reading part into its own function with a clean interface to the caller. It also reads from stdin; change to `fscanf` is simple.

Also the printing part is straight-forward, just loop over all rows. and print each column.

Note that this code will allocate at most `GROW_LENGTH - 1` unused rows. Set to 1 to have no overhead at all, but that is less efficient, as `realloc` is called fore every row. The best balance depends on the application, OS, etc.

Comment: @Christophe: OP clearly uses a fixed column layout. You version does not work for variable width either. Also you don't. Still this is no reason to DV. The typos have been corrected, this is apparently a fragment. Your code also does not compile as-is.

Answer (score 1):

First,  your arguments to `fscanf` don't match the format string.  `mymatrix[0]` is an `int *`, so `&mymatrix[0]` is an `int **`.  Compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` will warn you of this.

Also, you allocate space for a 1 element array of `int *`, but then you don't populate that pointer.

You need to allocate an array of 2 `int` to assign to the first element of `mymatrix`, then pass the address of each of those to `fscanf`:

```
int **mymatrix;
mymatrix = malloc(sizeof(int*)*1);    // don't cast the return value of malloc
mymatrix[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);  // same here
fscanf(file, "%d", &mymatrix[0][0]);
fscanf(file, ";%d", &mymatrix[0][1]);
```

Then you print them like this:

```
printf("%d",  mymatrix[0][0]);
printf(" %d", mymatrix[0][1]);
```

When reading each subsequent line, you'll need to `realloc` instead of `malloc` and keep track of how many lines you have and which line you're on.

Comment: I am using VS and It doesn't let me to not cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: @acon__ If that's the case, then you're probably compiling with the C++ compiler instead of the C compiler.

Comment: @acon__: Never compile C code with a C++ compiler! They are different languages. Even if some construct have identical syntax&grammar, they can can have different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the other fine answers, why not use a *pointer to array of int 2* (or whatever the size of your elements are)? In your circumstance, this is an optimal approach. There is no need to use a *pointer to pointer to int*. That complicates allocation and freeing of the memory. A *pointer to array* gives you single allocation of blocks, single freeing of all allocated memory and the 2D indexing you desire.

If you are reading from your file and storing a collection of integer pairs, you need only use a *pointer to array*, e.g.

```
    int (*arr)[2] = NULL;
```

That makes allocation with either `malloc` or `calloc` a single call to allocate storage an initial number of pairs, and makes freeing the memory a single call. For example, if you have a variable `maxn` of `64`, then to allocate a block of memory to hold the first `64` pairs of integers read from the file, you need only:

```
     arr = calloc (maxn, sizeof *arr);
```

There is no need for a separate call to allocate storage for every 2-integers, when your reach your initial limit of `64`, you simply `realloc` your array and keep going. The following uses a constant `MAXN` to `realloc` for an additional `64` pairs each time the current index `idx` reaches the limit `maxn` (the new block of memory is also zeroed):

```
    if (++idx == maxn) {
        printf ("\n  reallocating %zu to %zu\n", maxn, maxn + MAXN);
        size_t szelem = sizeof *arr;
        void *tmp = realloc (arr, (maxn + MAXN) * szelem);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "realloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);                
        }
        arr = tmp;
        memset (arr + maxn * szelem, 0, MAXN * szelem);
        maxn += MAXN;
    }
```

Putting all the pieces together and using a few simply error checking functions for convenience, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* constants for number of columns, buffer chars, and initial allocation */
enum { NCOL = 2, MAXC = 32, MAXN = 64 };

void *xcalloc (size_t nmemb, size_t sz);
void *xrealloc (void *ptr, size_t psz, size_t *nelem);
FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = {0};
    char *fmt = "%d;%d";
    int (*arr)[NCOL] = NULL;
    size_t i, idx = 0, maxn = MAXN;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? xfopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    /* alloc mem for array of MAXN elements */
    arr = xcalloc (maxn, sizeof *arr);

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line of input */
        int a, b;                       /* parse line for values */
        if (sscanf (buf, fmt, &a, &b) != NCOL) continue;
        arr[idx][0] = a, arr[idx][1] = b;
        if (++idx == maxn)              /* realloc as needed  */
            arr = xrealloc (arr, sizeof *arr, &maxn);
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" array[%3zu][0] : %4d    [1] : %d\n",
                i, arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);

    free (arr);     /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}

/** xcalloc allocates memory using calloc and validates the return. */
void *xcalloc (size_t nmemb, size_t sz)
{   register void *memptr = calloc (nmemb, sz);
    if (!memptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xcalloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return memptr;
}

/** realloc 'ptr' to array of elements of 'psz' to 'nelem + MAXN' elements */
void *xrealloc (void *ptr, size_t psz, size_t *nelem)
{   void *tmp = realloc ((char *)ptr, (*nelem + MAXN) * psz);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "realloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);                
    }
    memset (tmp + *nelem * psz, 0, MAXN * psz);  /* zero new memory */
    *nelem += MAXN;
    return tmp;
}

/** fopen with error checking - short version */
FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode)
{   FILE *fp = fopen (fn, mode);
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xfopen() error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        // return NULL;      /* choose appropriate action */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

**Example Input**

With an initial allocation for `64` pairs, reallocation is forces in order to read the entire file. (you can set the initial size at 1 and `realloc` on every iteration, but that is highly inefficient -- the initial size for `MAXN` must be at least 1, and should be set to some reasonably anticipated number of elements given your data)

```
$ cat dat/2d_data.txt
1;354
2;160
3;205
4;342
...
98;464
99;130
100;424
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_ptr2array_realloc <dat/2d_data.txt
 array[  0][0] :    1    [1] : 354
 array[  1][0] :    2    [1] : 160
 array[  2][0] :    3    [1] : 205
 array[  3][0] :    4    [1] : 342
...
 array[ 97][0] :   98    [1] : 464
 array[ 98][0] :   99    [1] : 130
 array[ 99][0] :  100    [1] : 424
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilites* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/array_ptr2array_realloc <dat/2d_data.txt
==2796== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2796== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2796== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2796== Command: ./bin/array_ptr2array_realloc
==2796==
 array[  0][0] :    1    [1] : 354
 array[  1][0] :    2    [1] : 160
 array[  2][0] :    3    [1] : 205
 array[  3][0] :    4    [1] : 342
...
 array[ 97][0] :   98    [1] : 464
 array[ 98][0] :   99    [1] : 130
 array[ 99][0] :  100    [1] : 424
==2796==
==2796== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2796==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2796==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,536 bytes allocated
==2796==
==2796== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2796==
==2796== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2796== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Look over all the answers and let me know if you have any further questions. Using a *pointer to array* makes a whole lot of sense in a number of situations such as this. It simplifies allocation and freeing of memory and preserves your 2D indexing as well.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using a pointer to an array. I am relatively new to programming so I can't think that creative. Your example was a bit above my level, but I have learned a lot of things. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: It is nothing fancy, it is simply the difference between `int *array[n];` (*an array of pointers* - n of them) and `int (*array)[n];` (*a pointer to an array of n int*). The first is `n` pointers to `int`, the second a single pointer to an *array* of `n int`. No magic, it just follows the C operator precedence rules, you read what is inside `(...)` first. Thus in `int (*array)[];` you read `*array` (pointer) to `[]` (an array).

Comment: Got it. But the fancy part of it is the things that I haven't learned yet, like `size_t` , `enum` , `register` and some other functions.

Comment: Fair enough, `size_t` is just a type you see that covers the positive range of `int` (you can't have negative lengths, etc...), a global `enum` allows you to create constants rather than 3 lines of `#define NCOL 3`, ... and `register` just hints to the compiler that this value will be used immediately, so try to keep the value in a register if possible instead of paging out to cache. Take it slow, there is a lot to learn, but it is a whole lot less work to learn it right the first time `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If `mymatrix` were defined as `int mymatrix[3][2]`, you could read the first line doing:

```
fscanf(file, "%d;%d", &mymatrix[0][0], &mymatrix[0][1]);
```

The same code would work with `mymatrix` defined as `int **mymatrix`, if it would point to a dynamically initialized array of pointers to arrays of `int` as follows:

```
mymatrix=(int**)calloc(lines, sizeof(int*)); // intialize the array of array
for (inti=0; i<lines; i++) 
    mymatrix[i]=(int*)calloc(cols, sizeof(int));  //intialise each array
```

The number of `lines` and `cols` of the matrix could then be defined at runtinme.

Comment: `int **mymatrix` is a pointer to pointer, never an "array of array".

Comment: @Olaf technically you're of course right, as it's a pointer to pointer.  But if mymatrix shall represent a matrix, it has to point to an array of `int*`, each of it having to point to an array of `int`.  I've edited slightly the wording to avoid the confusion.

Comment: No, it has not! Please see my answer.

Comment: @Olaf, you have the right to propose solutions using fixed number of columns.  But I think it's unfaire to downvote correct answers that use a different approach.

Comment: Your code contains other flaws (unnecessary casting, magic numbers) and does not include the relevant part: how to enlarge the matrix. Also I already wrote your statement "array of array" is clearly wrong. A pointer is not an array! Try `sizeof(mymatrix)`

Comment: @Olaf I think you have not read my clarifying edit, although I attempted to address your criticism. As a reminder, according to the standard,  *The calloc function allocates space for an **array** of nmemb objects, each of whose size is size. The space is initialized to all bits zero*.

Comment: Yes, but the elements are not arrays (they are for `int (*)[]`), but pointers. So: it is a pointer to an array of pointers. As I wrote: try the `sizeof`. To clarify: I do not criticise using that double indirection (although I disagree it is appropriate here), but the incorrect naming. There is already enough confusion about pointers and arrays in C. No need for higher-rep users to add to it. Feel free to drop me a comment if you have remove the flaws (I think it will need some more words, though).

Comment: @Olaf if I have a pointer that points to an array (according to the C11 standard) how shall I describe it better that saying that it points to an array ?  I don't get what is confusing here ?  And I don't understand this higher-rep remark either !

Comment: I agree there is no snappy term for this. But applying the same naming rules as for the first indirection, it might be called "pointer to array of pointers to array of `int`". Still not exact, but I can live with it. (Yes, that is as clumsy as the construct itself :-)

Comment: Actually, according to the C standard, you have a pointer that points to "the first element" of said array. As much as an array decays to for all but three exceptions. Anyway, the edit is ok.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to `malloc` the memory to `mymatrix[0]`.

```
mymatrix[0]= (int *) malloc ( sizeof (int) *2);
```

Also, in `mymatrix malloc`, 1 actually means the maximum number of rows you will have. So you can at max have 1 row as per that.

Comment: Curious why you cast `(int *)` the return value of `malloc()`.  It is allowable yet what value do you see in doing so?